# Unexpected value in the text box by setText() method, even though expected value by getText() method print in console

Tags: gettext, settext

I am a newbie and currently working on a project to build a Netflix-like desktop app on NetBeans. Users can select movies from a list to watch. I have two basic classes one to get, and the other one to set.

ONE TO GET:

[image: ONE TO GET]

OTHER ONE TO SET:

[image: OTHER ONE TO SET]

When a user clicks on jButton2('named Izle' on picture), the name of the film and the 'episode no.' passes to the filmIzleniyor class constructor, and then the film starts.

jButton2 SCREEN:

[image: jButton2 SCREEN]

There are two text field on that frame, one shows the name, other shows the 'episode no.'. The program objects have an id attribute, and 1-50 of id's are cinema movies, the others (greater than 50) are TV series. Cinema movies 'episode no.' is 1. If the user selects a TV series, he must enter the 'episode no.' in the box.

filmIzleniyor SCREEN:

[image: filmIzleniyor SCREEN]

The problem is that if user selects a cinema movie (so there's no need to enter the episode no.) everything is OK, but if he selects a TV series then both text boxes on the frame show the first entry all the time. I mean in every attempt after the first attempt both text boxes repeat the first.

As you can see on pictures, I have tried some controls to detect, but nothing.

Print the value taken by getText method in the console shows the true value, but wrong text is written on the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that way:
I call the filmIzleniyor(int x, String y) constructor by using new keyword in another button's actionPerformed method, it's the first time to call that constructor in the program.  The second time to call, i use the new keyword again  then it creates another instance, so that the  contents of the text components are loading two times. İt shows the first content in the screen, i dont know why?.